# How to convert nested hierarchy of xml to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, xquery

Using MSSQL 2008 and XQUERY

Consider the following XML stored in a table:

```
<ROOT>
  <WrapperElement>
    <ParentElement ID=1>
      <Title>parent1</Title>
      <Description />
      <ChildElement ID="6">
        <Title>Child 4</Title>
        <Description />
        <StartDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</EndDate>
      </ChildElement>
      <ChildElement ID="0">
        <Title>Child1</Title>
        <Description />
        <StartDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</EndDate>
      </ChildElement>
      <ChildElement ID="8">
        <Title>Child6</Title>
        <Description />
        <StartDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2010-01-25T00:00:00</EndDate>
      </ChildElement>
    </ParentElement>
  </WrapperElement>
</Root>
```

I want to decompose this xml into something like

```
PE!ID | PE!Title | PE!Description | CE!ID | CE!Title | CE!StartDate |...
1     | parent1  |                | 6     | child 4  |  2010-... |
1     | parent1  |                | 0     | child1   | 2010-...  |
```

etc.

Note: there may be many ChildElements per ParentElement, in this example.
I've been experimenting with xquery however i've not been able to navigate through complex elements as such.

Basically, i'm trying to do the exact opposite of what FOR XML does to a table, only with a much more simplistic set of data to work with.

Any ideas on where to go next or how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the XML stored using a text (varchar/etc) or XML data type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this (I declared `@input` to be a XML datatype variable with your XML content - replace accordingly):

```
SELECT
    Parent.Elm.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ID',
    Parent.Elm.value('(Title)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Title',
    Parent.Elm.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Description',
    Child.Elm.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS 'ChildID',
    Child.Elm.value('(Title)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'ChildTitle',
    Child.Elm.value('(StartDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS 'StartDate',
    Child.Elm.value('(EndDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS 'EndDate'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/ROOT/WrapperElement/ParentElement') AS Parent(Elm)
CROSS APPLY
    Parent.Elm.nodes('ChildElement') AS Child(Elm)
```

You basically iterate over all the `/ROOT/WrapperElement/ParentElemet` nodes (as `Parent(Elm)` pseudo table), and for each of those entries, you then do a `CROSS APPLY` for the child elements contained inside that `ParentElement` and pluck out the necessary information.

Should work - I hope!